# Javascript validation is not working - as soon as one if statement is true, it stops all if statements?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

1st - If a textbox is filled in, the code stops there and doesn't continue.

2nd - by the email, it won't check the 2nd if statement, if the first one is true.

I think the 1st and 2nd problem are both the same, that as soon as it sees one thing true, it stops there.

**HTML**

```
    <form name="form" onSubmit="return validation()" method="post">
              <p>
                  <label class="tittle">Name:</label>
                  <span>
                  <input type="text" name="firstname"
                                placeholder="First Name" class="info"
                                size="25" maxlength="25" 
                                onBlur="return validateFirstName()">
                   <label class="fillerror" id="fillFirst">
                                    First name is required
            </label>
                            </span>

                            <span>
                                <input type="text" name="lastname"
                                placeholder="Last Name" class="info"
                                size="25" maxlength="25"
                                onBlur="return validateLastName()">
                                <label class="fillerror" id="fillLast">
                                    Last name is required
                                </label>
                            </span>
                        </p>


                        <p>
                            <label class="tittle">Email:</label>
                            <span>
                                <input type="text" name="newEmail"
                                placeholder="Email" class="info"
                                size="25" maxlength="50"
                                onBlur="return validateEmail()">
                                <label class="fillerror" id="fillemail">
                                    Email address is required
                                </label>
                            </span>
                            <span>
                                <input type="text" name="retypedNewEmail" 
                                placeholder="Confirm Email" class="info"
                                size="25" maxlength="50"
                                onBlur="return asd()">
                                <label class="fillerror" id="fillemailConf">
                                    Email address confirmation is required
                                </label>
                                <label class="fillerror" id="fillemailConfirm">
                                    Email addresses do not match
                                </label>
                            </span>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label class="tittle">Password:</label>
                            <span>
                                <input type="password" name="newPassword"
                                placeholder="Password" class="info"
                                size="25" maxlength="15"
                                onBlur="return validatePassword()">
                                <label class="fillerror" id="fillpass">
                                    Password is required
                                </label>
                            </span>
                            <span>
                                <input type="password" 
                                name="retypedNewPassword"
                                placeholder="Confirm Password" class="info"
                                size="25" maxlength="15"
                                onBlur="return validateConfPassword()">
                                <label class="fillerror" id="fillpassConf">
                                    Password confirmation is required
                                </label>
                            </span>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <span id="sign">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="sign" checked>
                                Sign up for our Emails
                            </span>
                            <input type="button" name="register"
                            value="Register" class="register"
                            onClick="return validateFirstName(),
                            validateLastName(), validateEmail(),
                            validateConfEmail(), validatePassword(),
                            validateConfPassword();">
                        </p>
                        </form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function xValidate(inbox, fill)
    {
        inbox.style.backgroundColor="rgba(255, 0, 0, .1)";
        inbox.style.borderLeft="3px solid red";
        fill.style.display="block";
    }
    function yValidate(inbox, fill)
    {
        inbox.style.backgroundColor="white";
        inbox.style.borderLeft="3px solid rgb(169, 184, 1)";
        fill.style.display="none";
    }


function validateFirstName()
{   
    var frstnm = document.forms["form"] ["firstname"].value;

    if (frstnm==null || frstnm=="" || frstnm==" ")
    {
        var inbox = document.forms["form"] ["firstname"];
        var firstname = document.getElementById("fillFirst");
        xValidate(inbox, firstname);
    }
    else
    {
        var inbox = document.forms["form"] ["firstname"];
        var firstname = document.getElementById("fillFirst");
        yValidate(inbox, firstname);
    }
}   

function validateLastName()
{
    var lstnm = document.forms["form"] ["lastname"].value;

    if (lstnm==null || lstnm=="" || lstnm==" ")
    {
        var inbox = document.forms ["form"] ["lastname"];
        var lastname = document.getElementById("fillLast");
        xValidate(inbox, lastname);
    }
    else
    {
        var inbox = document.forms ["form"] ["lastname"];
        var lastname = document.getElementById("fillLast");
        yValidate(inbox, lastname);
    }
}



function validateEmail()
{
    var eml = document.forms["form"] ["newEmail"].value;

    if (eml==null || eml=="" || eml==" ")
    {
        var inbox = document.forms ["form"] ["newEmail"];
        var newEmail = document.getElementById("fillemail");
        xValidate(inbox, newEmail);
    }
    else
    {
        var inbox = document.forms ["form"] ["newEmail"];
        var newEmail = document.getElementById("fillemail");
        yValidate(inbox, newEmail);
    }
}

function validateConfEmail()
{
    var confeml = document.forms["form"] ["retypedNewEmail"].value;

    if (confeml==null || confeml=="" || confeml==" ")
    {
        var inbox = document.forms ["form"] ["retypedNewEmail"];
        var newEmail = document.getElementById("fillemailConf");
        xValidate(inbox, newEmail);
    }
    else
    {
        var inbox = document.forms ["form"] ["retypedNewEmail"];
        var newEmail = document.getElementById("fillemailconf");
        yValidate(inbox, newEmail);
    }

    var confirmEmail = document.forms["form"] ["newEmail"].value;

   if (document.forms["form"] ["retypedNewEmail"].value != document.forms["form"] ["newEmail"].value)
    {
        var inbox = document.forms ["form"] ["retypedNewEmail"];
        var newEmail = document.getElementById("fillemailConf");
        xValidate(inbox, newEmail);
    }
    else
    {
        var inbox = document.forms ["form"] ["retypedNewEmail"];
        var newEmail = document.getElementById("fillemailConf");
        yValidate(inbox, newEmail);
    }
}
```

Comment: I took away all the returns, but to no avail.  Also, what do u mean by i misused label elements?

Comment: At first, you're returning `false/true` to system, but return values send to `onblur` don't have any special meaning. In general, when `return` is found during function execution, the execution of that function stops immediately, any code after `return` statement will not be executed. Please check also [`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label).

Comment: I deleted all returns in javascript. there wasn't any changes in the website.

Comment: Now you've to take a look at you Dev console, maybe find some error messages there?

Comment: It's not that it doesn't work, it works but as soon as an if statement is false, the rest if statements become false too. Try it out on your html editor, if I'm not explaining it correctly.

Comment: No, it's all about that, for example: `<input name="retypedNewEmail" onBlur="return asd()">`, what is  `asd()`?

Comment: I'm getting so annoyed from javascript!! I really don't want to give up and stop using it!!

Comment: Please ease your life and use console, it tells you what went wrong...

Comment: what do you mean by console? do you mean in chrome, right click -  inspect element>

Comment: It means press `F12`. Keep a cool head though, we don't need to know that you don't like javascript, it doesn't help at all. You should rather organize your ideas, then tidy your question up accordingly.

Comment: I think i finally figured it out!! I need to change the way i make 'style' in javasctript. But I don't know how to create a style (for css in javascript) besides for the way i did it. Can someone please shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code on Firefox and IE and added alerts to each function.
When clciked on 'Register' button, in Firefox, all the alerts were shown while in IE only firstName alert came up.

Reason:: function xValidate and yValidate was giving error in IE.

at line :: `inbox.style.backgroundColor="rgba(255, 0, 0, .1)";` SCRIPT380: Invalid property value.

I would suggest, check your console for any JS error, it should solve your problem.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried it in ie, and it acted the same way as chrome. I also tried taking away the function xValidate() and replaced the stuff with actual code, and that also didn't word. I need HELP!!

Comment: I think i finally figured it out!! I need to change the way i make 'style' in javasctript. But I don't know how to create a style (for css in javascript) besides for the way i did it. Can someone please shed some light on this?

Comment: you can take some pointers from this:http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/ and to detect browser:: `function getBrowserName() {
 var browserName = "";

 var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
 if ( ua.indexOf( "opera" ) != -1 ) {
 browserName = "opera";
 } else if ( ua.indexOf( "msie" ) != -1 ) {
 browserName = "msie";
 } else if ( ua.indexOf( "safari" ) != -1 ) {
 browserName = "safari";
 } else if ( ua.indexOf( "mozilla" ) != -1 ) {
 if ( ua.indexOf( "firefox" ) != -1 ) {
 browserName = "firefox";
 } else {
 browserName = "mozilla";
 }
 }

return browserName;
};`